# Can not run react native other than from CLI

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am able to run my react-native app from CLI using
**react-native run-android**
command but if i close it once and try to re-open manually it is stuck in Splash-screen

There as I am able to close and reopen manually for iOS for the same app

[Here is my react environment info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9Tdp.png)

I also tried making and apk using instructions from this link
https://www.techup.co.in/how-to-create-a-test-build-react-native-android/
and i installed in a physicall device but same as emulator it is stuck in Splash-screen

[Project packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPT7y.png)

[MainActivity.java from android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2bnY.png)

Splash-screen is created with this
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen

[App file part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jy1e.jpg)

[App file part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klx4C.jpg)

[App file part3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrAjU.jpg)

Comment: Do you get any error logs in the terminal where your metro bundler is running? It's possible the app crashed and is stuck on the splash screen since it gets open separately from the rest of the react-native code

Comment: @anya no i didn't get any log from either React-native console or Android Studio logcat

Comment: @JoseLora I am not anything extra only installing these modules and implementing it here and i am not getting a working build. I even tried to create a new project and working on it again and same issue pops up

Comment: With the help of a colleague I found out that the launch activity was misplaced to Splash instead of MainActivity in AndroidManifest so after changing it the issue got resolved